# MS Teams broke my PC - can it be recovered?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams

Several of the clients I work with use MS Teams for online meetings, so I often switch between different accounts.

This has been working fine for years, but this morning when logging in a policy of the client seems to have been applied. The PC restarted and now displays the client's logo and messages on startup, and prompts me to change my password before continuing (I haven't gone any further than this in case it makes things worse).

I contacted their helpdesk but was told "Ah yes we don't recommend you sign in to company teams accounts from your own PC" and that the only way to fix it is to re-image the hard drive.

So beyond arguing the toss about whether I was actually warned or not by Teams or the client (given the MFA and associated pallava I may have clicked through a warning but I'm not sure that's the case) is this likely that re-imaging is the only fix?

It must have only taken a minute or so so I can't believe too much damage was done.

I have a separate data drive containing all the really important stuff so I'm hoping that at least will be salvageable.

And of course I have a backup - just not a very recent one!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about *corporate policies* and their impact on a personal PC.

Comment: It also sounds like group policies were applied to the entire machine just not Microsoft Teams if a logo is displayed at system startup. Especially if it requires reinstalling Windows to fix the problem.

Comment: So how could that happen? How would logging into an MS Teams account do that? The PC itself was not logged into the client's domain.

Comment: In other words, you allowed the client to push policies to your personal PC. It seems you would have no knowledge of *what other changes* have been made, as well, so the best recourse is to save any recent data and then use an old disk image to restore the drive... or perhaps, reinstall OS from ISO. In the future, consider having multiple instances of the OS, one for each client and one for personal use (possibly on VM).

Comment: So it seems. Still no idea how it occurred! Thanks.

Comment: When you sign in to certain Microsoft applications, you are presented with a choice to link this account. This is a trap. You probably fell for it. I don't know whether this can be undone.

Comment: @DanielB Apparently this is what happened. It could be undone by the domain admins un-applying the policy(s) - assuming no other damage - but you need a sympathetic admin for that, not one who works from home that you may have just woken up.

Comment: In the future, Teams' web client is pretty capable, and logging into that should not apply any policies outside the browser. This company has a really poor configuration if they do not have a way for external contractor to connect into their environment in a controlled and limited way that doesn't take over their devices, but the damage has already been done. I'd beat down their doors for a bit, but it is very possible that you will need to reinstall Windows to get back fully what you had before.